# Error when trying to retrieve data from MySQL database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

So this is what I have:

```
<?php

$db_host = "localhost";
$db_username = "root";
$db_pass = "";
$db_name = "OnlineBulletinBoardDB";

@mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass") or die ("Could no connect to    MySQL");
@mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die ("No database");

$query="SELECT PostSubject, FROM postings;";

$result=mysql_query($query);

mysql_close();

?>

<H1>Post Subject</H1>

<?php echo mysql_num_rows($result); ?>
```

But its not working, when I try and run it gives me some error on the last line.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you specify the "an error on the last line" ?

Comment: Dont worry guys, i found the error - it was the comma in the sql statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$query="SELECT PostSubject, FROM postings;";`  is invalid sql

try `$query="SELECT PostSubject FROM postings";`

Comment: @Jason - no problem mate - I have been caught out like that on much simpler things (>.<)